# Company terminates employees without any warning letter?

Tags: management, termination

Is it common for a company to terminate its employees without any warning letter in advanced?

Comment: It depends on the circumstances.  If there was gross misconduct or a risk of a disgruntled employee causing damage, then it's not unheard of to walk someone immediately off the premises.

Comment: Can you please add a country tag? In some countries this is legal and therefore might even be normal, in some it's highly illegal and therefore cannot be "normal". You will not get a globally correct answer to your question.

Comment: I see, as each country has different rules, I will delete this post. Thanks!

Comment: @Lewis Why delete it? Clarify it. Others may have a similar question.

Comment: For example, in France, it's mandatory to offer the employee a preliminary interview where he is supposed to be able to defend itself. It's a joke, when it happens, the decision is already taken, but it's mandatory.

Answer (score 11):

That depends on many factors:

- **Country:** Many countries have laws in place to prevent this under normal circumstances, but some do not. The USA for instance, has largely got "at-will employment" meaning you can be fired at any time with no notice for any or no reason (besides a few protected ones).
- **Circumstances:** After gross misconduct or committing a crime on the job, most countries allow immediate dismissal without warning. If you do something really bad, like steal from the company or punch someone, expect to not get the chance to improve.
- **Company Standing:** In some cases, like with liquidation in bankruptcy, employees sometimes can be terminated (more appropriate term is laid off) without notice. If there is no money to pay them, then nobody can enforce a notice period.
- **Company Policy:** In places where instant termination is legal, still many companies have policies about this. Check with your company to see their policies on terminations.

Comment: I'd also add *leaving to join a competitor* to your circumstances. I've seen people be escorted out after revealing they're leaving to work elsewhere and being put on gardening leave for the remainder of their notice period.

Comment: @SLC But "being put on gardening leave" is not an immediate termination. In that case the employee is still officially employed until the end of the notice period. They are just not permitted on company grounds anymore. But they are still entitled to any contractually guaranteed benefits, including payment.

Comment: In the US, many layoffs terminate as of the notification of the termination even when the company is not going under completely. Generally they escort you right off the premises immediately after the meeting where you are told. Layoffs are almost never announced in advance, although politically smart employees can often see the signs that something is coming.

Comment: @HLGEM Generally speaking if you're seeing a lot of "folding" of managers and managers leaving without replacement is generally a sign that something is going on.

Comment: @Dan or a sudden increase in Manger-only closed door meetings. Especially if the managers in the meetings don't necessarily work closely together day-to-day.